# Is it appropriate to have a template class with constructor overloading for each "type"

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to using templates.

Is it appropriate to make a template class using constructor overloading for the various actual types?

For example:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    A(..will receive paramaters for a specific type T);
    A(..will receive DIFFERENT params for a different type T);
}
```

The code will compile because all functionality for each instantiation works, however logically (and practically) speaking, each constructor will be called depending on the type that I am actually using.

This suits my purpose well, but is this a correct "programming mindset"?

---

To be more specific - using SFML, here is what I am referring to,
one will be a sprite and the other a shape, but with common functionality but exclusive too, such as the setColor or setTexture functions. What I mean is there will be no logical sense in calling the second constructor for T as a sprite:

```
template <typename T>
class GameObject {
public:
    GameObject(sf::Texture& texture, sf::Vector2f pos)
    {       

        m_drawable.setTexture(texture);
        m_drawable.setOrigin(m_drawable.getGlobalBounds().width / 2, m_drawable.getGlobalBounds().height / 2);
        m_drawable.setPosition(pos);
    }
    GameObject(sf::Color color, sf::Vector2f pos)
    {
        m_drawable.setColor(color);
        m_drawable.setPosition(pos);
    }




private:
    T m_drawable;

};
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you show an actual example of what you're trying to achieve? If all the overloads do the same thing, then why overload at all?

Comment: Like anything else, it makes sense to overload only if the overloads do different things.  Yes, you can have a constructor for `T` and other constructors for other types, if really needed.

Comment: "This suits my purpose well, but is this a correct "programming mindset"?" Short answer: yes. If I understood you right, you want to overload a template class with different types - that is how template classes are used. You have to keep in mind different types needs different methods. Just today I checked out EAs faster vector stl and you will see how templates can be used for different types https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/vector.h

Comment: This seems fishy to me. Not necessarily wrong in general, but possibly not-great in your specific case, depending on some details. I don't have a good feel for what you plan to do, though. So for one instantiation of this class, `T` will be a sprite class, while in the other `T` will be a shape class? Why are the drawables being configured by `GameObject`? What is the purpose/role of `GameObject`? (Is `GameObject` trying to do too many things in one class?)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you would have only `GameObject<Sprite>` and `GameObject<Shape>` and use template to factorize some common code, but both classes have specific interface.

Then, IMO, it is bad to provide in interface methods to not use.

`std::vector` provides some methods which has pre-requires on type `T` (`v.resize(count)` requires default insertable). But it is generic classes, combination would be huge, so acceptable IMO.

I think that non-common methods should be removed from `GameObject<T>`

- In C++20, there is `requires` which allow to "remove" methods conditionally:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class GameObject {
  public:
      GameObject(sf::Texture&, sf::Vector2f pos) requires(std::is_same_v<Sprite, T>);
      GameObject(sf::Color, sf::Vector2f pos) requires(std::is_same_v<Shape, T>);
      // ...
  };
  ```

  SFINAE is an alternative for previous standard.
- You might have 2 new classes `GameSprite`/`GameShape` which use/inherit a cleaned `GameObject<T>` as implementation detail.
- Alternatively, you might use (`friend`) free function for the distinct behavior

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class GameObject {
      GameObject(T&& t) : m_drawable(std::move(t)){}
  public:
      friend GameObject<Sprite> GameSprite(sf::Texture& texture, sf::Vector2f pos) {
          Sprite sprite;

          sprite.setTexture(texture);
          sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getGlobalBounds().width / 2, sprite.getGlobalBounds().height / 2);
          sprite.setPosition(pos);
          return GameObject<Sprite>{std::move(sprite)};
      }
      friend GameObject<Shape> GameShape(sf::Color color, sf::Vector2f pos) { /*..*/}
      // ...
  };
  ```